# Attachments as documents

Tags: apex

I want to add my custom object attachments as personal documents dynamically..
(I want to save attachments as salesforce documents dynamically how to do this any suggesions..

Comment: One option is using dataloader export the attachment.and insert the file paths into documents as a one time action.

Comment: No i want to get from different users records attachments

Comment: So you want to write some code to read attachments and create Salesforce Documents out of them?

Comment: ok is there any example code for that